# Dealing with math acronyms from acro package in math mode

Tags: math-mode, acro

I'm using `acro` package for my acronyms. Some of the acronyms are equation variables, so I'd like tu use them in math mode. The problem is when I use the acronym in math mode, I get the error `Missing \endgroup inserted. This is me trying to use $\acs{de}=`. How can I use acronyms written between `$ $`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\DeclareAcronym{de}{
short=$d_{e}$,
long=especific diameter
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
This is me trying to use $\acs{de}=12$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `short=\ensuremath{d_{e}}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

@clemens Solved the problem, I just used `\ensuremath` command

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\DeclareAcronym{de}{
short=\ensuremath{d_{e}},
long=especific diameter
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
This is me trying to use $\acs{de}=12$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Daniel, here $d_e$ shown by \printacronyms will not be a bold symbol. But by default if we use any acronym (without \ensuremath{}) in our document and use \printacronyms, short form of that acronyms will be shown in bold character in list of acronyms. So, short form of few acronym (without \ensuremath{}) will be in bold and few with \ensuremath{} will not be in bold. How to print all the short forms shown in list of acronyms in bold characters.