# Nomenclature and abbreviations

Tags: nomenclature

I have a TeX file including different chapters for my thesis. Each chapter is in a different TeX file imported in the main TeX file. I was wondering how to add the list of nomenclatures and abbreviations to my thesis. Should I write all of them one by one?

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{\bf Table of Contents}}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\bf LIST OF TABLES}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\bf LIST OF FIGURES}}


bla bla bla

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
{\let\oldnumberline\numberline\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}\listoftables}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
{\let\oldnumberline\numberline\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}\listoffigures}
```

Comment: The fact that the chapters are in different files has no relevance. More important is how you define the nomenclature and abbreviation entries.

Comment: So how can I do that? I did for abbreviation but nomenclature I have no idea?

Answer (score 1):

I recommand `acro` package to create abbreviations and nomenclature. You can define both abbreviations and nomenclature using the `\DeclareAcronym{}{}` command by just changing the class name.
For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\DeclareAcronym{GMC}{
    short = GMC,
    long = G.M.Constructions,
    class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{SPM}{
    short = SPM,
    long = Sectro photo meter,
    class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{NY}{
    short = NY,
    long = New York,
    class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{L}{
    short = L,
    long = Litre,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{mg}{
    short = mg,
    long = Milli gram,
    class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{mL}{
    short = mL,
    long = Milii Litre,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{g}{
    short = g,
    long = Gram,
    class = abbrev
}
\begin{document}
    \ac{GMC} is one of the famous company. \ac{SPM} is used for analytical study of compounds. I live in \ac{NY}.   $1$ \ac{L} = $1000$ \ac{mL}. Similarly, $1$ \ac{g} = $1000$ \ac{mg}.
    \printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
    \printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]       
\end{document}
```

The result is 
[image]

You can create separate tex file for each chapter and you can use the `\ac{}` in any of the file if once you defined all the acronym in the preamble of the document.

Comment: Why are the 2 lists "Abbreviations" and "Nomenclature" the same and why don't I see `mL` and `L`?

Comment: @albert I edited the answer. Previously, both ```\printacronyms[]``` statement was written for abbreviation so both the results are same. Now, I changed the second list for nomenclature.

Comment: I actually need math based nomenclature sir

Comment: This might be of little help to you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392714/209901