# Extra space with \ensuremath in acro

Tags: spacing, acro

Following [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392714/dealing-with-math-acronyms-from-acro-package-in-math-mode/392723), I have in my acronyms the same pattern I define in a `\newcommand\BS`.

However, when I use `\ensuremath` and type my acronym with no math environment, I get an obvious extra space before and after, whereas it's alright if I put it in math mode.

[image]

It has to do with [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro) but even if I follow the advice to put extra `{ }` inside `\ensuremath{}` to surround my expression, I still get extra spacing.

NB :If you tell me "well put your acronym in math mode then", i'd reply "well I have to do that along my 1500 pages, so how can I avoid that ? :) " and get the proper spacing in text ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{acro}
%\usepackage{xspace}

% with extra {} inside \ensuremath{ } 
\newcommand{\BS}[2]{ \ensuremath{ { \mathcal{#1}_{\mathcal{#2} } } } }

\DeclareAcronym{ki}{
short= \BS{K}{I},
long = Knock-In
}
\begin{document}

When I use \acs{ki} in text there is obviously extra space before and after my acronym.

When I use $\acs{ki}$ in math there is the right space before and after my acronym.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you add all these spaces in the definition?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well it was for readibility of my code and thought we did not care about spaces but it seems that we do ! Sorry for this silly question Ulrike :/

Comment: well one difference between math and text is that spaces matters differently in text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's obvious once you say it :) Thank and sorry for the silly question. Shall we close it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're responsible of those spaces. I denote by `!` the significant ones and with `x` those that are ignored because they are processed in math mode:

```
\newcommand{\BS}[2]{ \ensuremath{ { \mathcal{#1}_{\mathcal{#2} } } } }
                    !            x x                          x x x !
```

Don't use `\ensuremath` in the definition of `\BS`: you gain nothing in being able to type `some \BS{K}{I} text` instead of the clearer and more semantic `some $\BS{K}{I}$ text`. There are also useless braces that are better removed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\newcommand{\BS}[2]{\mathcal{#1}_{\mathcal{#2}}}

\DeclareAcronym{ki}{
  short= \ensuremath{\BS{K}{I}},
  long = Knock-In
}

\begin{document}

When I use \acs{ki} in text

When I use $\acs{ki}$ in math

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Guilty :) I must confess when I see code with `expl3` the extra spaces give more readibility in the code. Wrong choice of mine to generalize.